# Suitable "h" parameter for the Kernel UD() function in R other than "href" to encompass all spatial points in the data

Tags: r, kernel-density

Here is my R-script that results in the attached output for 50 and 95% occupancy contours. But I am noticing how much ever I tweak the "grid", "extent" and "h" values, it does not encompass most of the spatial points. I found the smoothing parameter "h" is the one to manipulate but giving it either "LSCV" or number did not help.

What else could I try?

```
library(sp)
library(adehabitatHR)
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

# read in a .csv which contains lat and long for your data points

Bat1 <- read.csv("D:/Bats/Bat1.csv", header = TRUE) 

# create spatial points object

#datapoints<-SpatialPoints(cbind(Bat1$Lat,Bat1$Lon)) 

#kud <- kernelUD(datapoints, h= "href", grid = 3000, extent = 5.0 ) #kernel density utilization distribution (h=smoothing factor)

image(kud)

hr50<-getverticeshr(kud, percent= 50,unout = "m2") #convert into vector object, use 50 for quartic kernel

hr95<-getverticeshr(kud, percent= 95,unout = "m2") #convert into vector object, use 95 for quartic kernel

# Convert to data frames for plotting
hr50df <- fortify (hr50)
hr95df <- fortify (hr95)

# Plot with ggplot2
ggplot () +
  geom_polygon (data = hr95df, aes (x = long, y = lat, fill = id, group = group), alpha = 0.5, color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  geom_polygon (data = hr50df, aes (x = long, y = lat, fill = id, group = group), alpha = 0.8, color = "black", size = 0.5) +
  coord_equal () +
  theme_void ()

# set coordinates and write to shapfile which can be projected in ArcGIS
WGScoor1<- hr50
proj4string(WGScoor1)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellips=WGS84")
raster::shapefile(WGScoor1, "D:/Bats/Bat1HR_50_new.shp")

WGScoor2<- hr95
proj4string(WGScoor2)<- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellips=WGS84")
raster::shapefile(WGScoor2, "D:/Bats/Bat1HR_95_new.shp")
```

[image: 50 and 95% KDE contours]

Comment: Are there any pointers I could get for this Q? I have looked up online and got no traction. Any direction is appreciated. TY - Prabha